# Width and height HTML attributes for images with different sizes inserted via database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a gallery of images with different sizes and whose paths are stored in a database. The images are fetched with PHP and a MySQL stored procedure. I have tried to add width and height attributes to the `<img>` with PHP:

```
width="<?php list($width, $height) = getimagesize($row['modal_img_src']); echo $width; ?>"
height="<?php list($width, $height) = getimagesize($row['modal_img_src']); echo $height; ?>"
```

but this obviously gives me the intrinsic dimensions not the ones the browser is actually using.

Would I need JavaScript to let the browser know about the actually used width and height of each image?

**EDIT:**
I could store width and height of each individual image in the database too.(?)

Comment: `<img style="width: 200px; height: 100px;" src="<path to img>" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly your goal is. The browser will generally be fine detecting intrinsic image sizes (one reason to add them is to reduce content shift when images are slower to load).

If you have specific sizes you want to display the image in, whatever its intrinsic size is you should offload that to the browser via CSS. Specifying things like `max-width`, `max-height` will likely get you where you need to be.

Alternatively, if you want more control you could use the CSS `background-image` property on a non-image element. That allows you to control the way in which it scales via `background-size`.

In my opinion either of these solutions are better than using JS for this case.

Also for completeness sake, if you do end up using `get_image_size` be sure to call it just once and check its return value.